# Should Hindu politicians support Brahmins according to scriptures?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins

Should Hindu politicians support Brahmins according to scriptures?

Is it a sin if Hindu politicians don't support Brahmins?

Please cite verses from scriptures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should Hindu politicians support Brahmins?

**Yes, they should support Brahmins according to scriptures.**

> Manu 9.313 - Even when fallen in the deepest distress, the king shall
>   not provoke the Brāhmaṇas; for if provoked, they would ruin him, along
>   with his army and conveyances.
>
> Manu 9.317 - Learned or unlearned, the Brāhmaṇa is a great divinity;
>   just as consecrated or unconsecrated, the fire is a great divinity.
>
> Manu 9.319 - Similarly even though they betake themselves to all sorts
>   of undesirable acts, yet Brāhmaṇas should be honoured in every way;
>   for they are the greatest divinity.
>
> Manu 9.322 - The Kṣatriya flourishes not without the Brāhmaṇa; the
>   Brāhmaṇa prospers not without the Kṣatriya; the Brāhmaṇa and the
>   Kṣatriya, when united, prosper here as also in the other world.
>
> Gautama (11.14).—‘It is declared in the Veda—“Kṣatriyas, who are
>   assisted by Brāhmaṇas, prosper and do not fall into distress.”’
>
> Vaśiṣṭha (19.4).—‘It is declared in the Veda—“A realm where a Brāhmaṇa
>   is appointed domestic priest prospers.”’

But this doesn't mean that Brahmanas shouldn't be punished, for the commentator *Medhatithi* says:

> When they betake themselves to forbidden acts, they shall be dealt and
>   punished according to law, gently, and not attacked with force, in the
>   manner of other castes.

Also Narada:

> Nārada (18.12).—‘On account of their dignity and sanctity, it is not
>   permitted to either advise or rebuke a King or a Brāhmaṇa, unless they
>   swerve from the path of duty.’

By "advise" it actually means "criticize," since kings have advisers.

Comment: Question is off-topic but how are kings politicians? Hindu politicians are obligated to follow the rule of the land not what Hindu scriptures say.

Comment: @sv. For Indian politicians who are Hindu Kshatriyas.